# Zero Operators on Complex Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

This is a problem from Kreyszig's Introdcutory Functional Analysis with Applications.

If for any $x$ in a complex Hilbert Space $<Tx, x> = 0$, show that $T\equiv 0$.

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\forall x, y$, we have following two equations:

\begin{align}
 <T(x+iy), x+iy> = 0 \\
 <T(x+y), x+y> = 0
\end{align}

Since $<Tx, x> = <Ty, y> = 0$, these two are equivalent to 
\begin{align}
   <Ty, x> - <Tx, y> = 0 \\
   <Ty, x> + <Tx, y> = 0
\end{align}
Because $x$ and $y$ are chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that $T \equiv 0$

Comment: But he said if $X$ is real inner product it isn't true